# Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet. Access is denied. Error processing resource

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am trying to display an XML file using ASP.NET C#, below is my code:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Display Model Report" OnClientClick="window.open('Model Report.xml');returnfalse;" />
```

This XML file is a database modeling report, it gives me this error when I run the code,

> Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet.Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later
>
> **Access is denied**. Error processing resource C:\Users\pchandra\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite1\Model Report....

Any kind of help greatly appreciated

Comment: THe user context that is accessing the file does not have read access to that file.  You need to allow the user account access to that shared folder.

Answer (score 0):

using this window.open your xml file must be relative to the page you are looking at... you should probably use the full path.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried to remove windows.open and then display the xml file using simple Response.Redirect but still I get the same error.

Comment: yes it does, it provides clarification on the reason for the problem occuring and provides enough information for the user to fix it. Obviously I dont know the full path and theres really no reason to ask when the answer is simple...